# Android - How to post achievements in a game on Google+

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-games

I followed the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart
It works nice to show and unlock achievements via the [GameClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html), but I would like to know if there is a way to post unlocked achievements on Google+.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this page](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share) help you? Please keep in mind that to attach any detailed information to the post you have to have it in your resources. GamesClient takes the achievement information from the internet, but you can't do it here.